# file upload excel exception

Tags: java, file, upload, jxl

I have a problem in uploading excel file, my Java code below

```
File newFile = new File("C:/sample.xls");
int firstColNo = 0;
int row = 0;
Cell cell;
Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(newFile);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(0);
    for (row = 1; row < 1005; row++) {
        LabelCell labelCell1 = sheet.findLabelCell("COMPOUND_ID");
            if (labelCell1 != null) {
                firstColNo = labelCell1.getColumn();
                cell = sheet.getCell(firstColNo, row);
                    if (cell.getContents() != null && cell.getContents().length() > 0) {                                            System.out.println(cell.getContents());
                } else {
                                        System.out.println("-");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

When I debug it I'm getting this exception

```
jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream
    at jxl.read.biff.CompoundFile.<init>(CompoundFile.java:116)
    at jxl.read.biff.File.<init>(File.java:127)
    at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:221)
    at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:198)
    at hello.FileUploadExample.doPost(FileUploadExample.java:63)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I'm using jxl.jar file for file upload.

Can anyone help me to solve it?

Comment: Probably duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497681/unable-to-recognize-ole-stream-excepion-while-connecting-to-excel

Comment: It seems that the upload is not the problem?

Comment: s upload is not the problem but wen im debugging this line        Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(newFile); i'm getting exception

Comment: -tostao, hi, i've seen the link, do u have the updated jxl jar

Answer (score 0):

On the stacktrace it is the

`at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:198`)

which is called in your code at

```
Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(newFile);
```

I have used POI and other excel library, not this , but it seems at that point can be a FileNotFoundException converted to a jxl.read.biff.BiffException or the library doesn't recognize the input file format.- because you gave a plain.txt renamed to .xls

Pls do a verification at least the Java level

```
if(!newFile.isFile()){
    return;
}
```

also you can check the length to not be 0 and so on.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497681/unable-to-recognize-ole-stream-excepion-while-connecting-to-excel) can be your solution.

I hope it helps you to find a direction.